# How to send funds from one personal PayPal account to another in PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I tried use [checkout api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/) in Paypal to send funds from one personal account to another, But after clicking the `continue` button, refreshed checkout page and didnt transfer the funds.

Here is the PHP code what I did:

```
private function sendDirectlyPayment(float $amount, string $currency, string $address, string $backUrl): array
{
    $params = [
        'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
        'purchase_units' => [
            [
                'amount' => [
                    'currency_code' => $currency,
                    'value' => (string) $amount
                ],
                'payee' => [
                        'email_address' => $address
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $data = $this->encodeData($params);
    $headers = $this->getAuthHeaders($data);
    $res = $this->execute(self::POST, '/v2/checkout/orders', $data, $headers);

    return $res;
}
```

[image: PayPal Checkout page]

Not sure how to make to work api properly.

Comment: What was the error message returned after the fund transfer did not work?

Answer (score 1):

You set up the payment correctly, and the payer is approving the payment. But you are missing the final 'capture' API step, so no transaction is created.  You need to implement the `v2/checkout/orders/.../capture` API call after approval.

---

The best way is to make two callable routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

----

The smart button gives the best user experience -- however, if for some reason your use case is better without it, then what you need to do is specify a `return_url` in the create order call. When the payer clicks continue and reaches the `return_url`, it is there when you would display an order review page and have a button that triggers the capture API call for the final action.

If you want to skip having a review page and do the capture immediately, this is also possible to do, but you need to set the `application_context` object's `user_action` parameter to `PAY_NOW`, so that the last button has appropriate text instead of 'Continue'.

Comment: I used `PAY_NOW` option as you suggested, and it worked. Thank you

Comment: I cant go to web page after click `Pay Now` button, it is refreshed again

Comment: Then there is a problem with your return_url. But you should be using the smart button instead

Comment: Since I'm doing in my local, I set it like that: 
`'redirect_urls' => [
     'return_url' => '127.0.0.1:3000/pay/',
     'cancel_url' => '127.0.0.1:3000/pay/'
 ]`

Comment: URLs have to start with http/https at the very least, no idea if IP addresses or non-standard ports would work.

Comment: tried with live url include https instead of local url, but same result. By the way, Should I   have to do something in my PayPal developer account setting?